# Displaying some data above data in a cell

Tags: jquery, css

I have the table defined as:

```
<table role="grid" style="height: auto;"><colgroup><col style="width:200px">
```

```
<tr data-uid="5b6a6a00-3dc5-44bd-b2a4-f7a04879385c" role="row" style="outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);">
<td role="gridcell"><span>795368339</span><span class="NoType" begin="338" end="348"> AMANULLAH</span><span class="PhoneNumber" begin="329" end="338" style="background-color: rgb(144, 238, 144);" data-original-title=""></span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/m7JLJ/

I need to display some data above the name or the phone number in the cell. It has to be toggled.

**How can I do it using CSS?**

I can toggle it using jQuery but I'm having difficulty displaying the data above the data. in the cell

Comment: You have lot of unwanted code and it is not tidy enough to read. Would you mind formatting it a little bit.

Comment: didnt got the question.. but it can be brought number and name by just `<br>` ..

Comment: Just did it. Hope this helps. Also update the jsfiddle

Comment: That code is very messy, but does the following work for you `$('.PhoneNumber:eq(0)').prepend("Something else<br />");`

Answer (score 0):

on the td (the data holder cell) aplly 'position:relative;'
on the span's (the data itself) aplly 'position:absolute;'

now they are on top of each other, you can toggle between them via jquery.

but now, the td height will be 0, so my advice is to add an empty span before the data like shown below;

**HTML:**

```
<td class="Holder">
    <span class="Filler"></span>
    <span class="Phone">01234567</span>
    <span class="OtherData">my name is</span>
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
.Holder
{
    position: relative;
}
.Phone, .OtherData
{
    position: absolute;
}
.Filler
{
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```